# If Google Ads bans your Adsense account, will your website rank drop from Google search?

Tags: google-adsense, search-results

Just wondering, if Google bans your Adsense account, will your site be hardly reached by people who use Google to search?

Comment: The question is why your Adsense account was banned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Search rankings are separate from Adsense. Anything that happens in Adsense won't affect your site's Google Search ranking.

However, consider the possibility that whatever happened to get your Adsense banned could also cause an issue in Google Search ranking.

In other words, Adsense doesn't affect Search, but outside factors can affect both at once.